# How do you reduce a java double to n significant digits?

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal, decimalformat, rounding-error

I am looking to print small digits (`doubles`) for the purpose of printing the errors in using the `Newton` & `Secant` methods.

One of my errors is `5.433306166802499E-5`

I'd like to print `5.4333E-5`

I thought of using `BigDecimal` but I am not familiar with this class.

Comment: You just want to format the number for printing. Don't mess around with the value (i.e. don't "reduce to n digits").

Comment: @ScaryWombat Disagree. He just wants to format a double for output.

Comment: @JimGarrison Ok, looks like I put too much weight on the title.

Answer (score 6):

> I am looking **to print** small digits (doubles)

```
System.out.printf("%.4e",  5.433306166802499E-5);
```

Result: `5.4333e-05`

*Note*: it doesn't *reduce* the precision of your original value, it just *prints* it with a lower precision.

Comment: You left out the "e" format specifier; I added it to make your answer actually work.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks, I don't know how I lost the `e`

Answer (score 2):

`double d = 5.433306166802499E-5;
BigDecimal dc = new BigDecimal(d);
dc = dc .round(new MathContext(3)); // desired significant digits
double rounded = dc .doubleValue();`

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use BigDecimal, it would then look as follows:

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(val).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
double scaled = d.doubleValue();
```

Or you could use:

```
Math.round(val*Math.pow(10, scale))/Math.pow(10, scale);
```

Comment: First example as too many commas, and if `val = 5.433306166802499E-5` as given in question, result is `1.0E-4`, which is far from the desired output of `5.4333E-5`.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the general question of reducing a double's significant digits, and not just the case of *printing* with `System.out.printf`:

If you're using Java: `Double.parseDouble(String.format("%1.4e", 5.433306166802499E-5))`

In Scala, you can use the `f` string interpolator, or the format method:

```
val a: Double = 5.433306166802499E-5
val reduced1: Double = f"$a%1.4e".toDouble
val reduced2: Double = "%1.4e".format(a).toDouble
```

Both are equal: `5.4333e-05`

Comment: The question asks about java but this answer is Kotlin.

Comment: My answer was for Scala. Not sure about the f string interpolator, but the `String.format` method should work for Java.